# Suggestion for django model for annual payment plans

Tags: django, model

I am using the default django user auth models for authentication in my django 3 app.

I want to offer users 3 plans either of which they can purchase.
Plan A, Plan B, Plan C. 
All 3 plans have different views accessibility but have same duration of 1 year.

What would be the best way to extend the User model to keep tab on which plan the user has paid for?
Also how do I 'expire' the plan after 1 year from date of purchase?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    none = 0
    planA = 1
    planB = 2
    planC = 3
    Plans = (
       (planA, _('Plan A')),
       (planB, _('Plan B')),
       (planC, _('Plan C')),
       )
    plan = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
       choices=Plans,
       default=none,
     )
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_subscribed = models.BooleanField(_('no'), default=False)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I wouldn't even touch the `User` model. Have one model which have all your plans. Then have another model(Membership kind) where you can save User model id with what planed they subscribe it with all other attributes like start_date etc...

Comment: Thats what I did...I created a new model UserSubscription.
Just wanted to know if its the best/recommended way to store such information in Django